# A tool or platform to build multiuser newspaper-like site?

Tags: cms, web, blog

Need a clue, what tool would be the best for creating site with features:

- you see it as a newspaper, mean, set of articles to read (aka news reader)
- your view can have various content according to your preferences or perspecitives aka: favorite authors, fav. subjects, most renowned authors etc.
- content (articles) is created by authors/users/members of site/platform
- author may disallow other members for comments or vote
- author may remove comments found offensive
- there's a system of commenting articles
- there's a system of voting or giving marks to articles
- there's a system of "gaining respect" and "grading" for articles and authors
- there's a system of feedback for a user containing inf. like:
  --> his articles with new comments
  --> his comments with new answers
  --> new articles form favorite authors
  --> new comments for observed articles

Possibility of inner messaging communication system would be a benefit.

If any CMS like Drupal Joomla WP than what extension. Any other tool? Built from scratch?